# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android - Cube rotation

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation

I'm trying to make a 6 color cube (1 color per face) that rotates around any axle. The rotation is not an issue but what I figured out is that the face that is drawn at last is the one that get rendered.

For example: The front face is red and the back one is green. When the cube starts to rotate, as I called "glDrawArrays" (that creates the red face) before the "glDrawArrays" (that creates the green face), whenever the faces get one above the other (due the rotation) I always see the green face, when I actually should see red, green, red, green etc.

How can I solve this issue? I tried to find information in the last days but didn't find the solution.

The code is below.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

GLSurfaceView myGLSurfaceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    myGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);      
    myGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    myGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(new RendererClass(this));

    setContentView(myGLSurfaceView);

    runnable.run();

}

// Test 2

static float variable2 = 0;

Handler myHandler = new Handler();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        myHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 20);
        variable2 += 1; 

    }
};

}
```

and

```
public class RendererClass implements Renderer {

int shaderProgram;

int variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation;
int variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation;
int variableToSayWhereTheMatrixShouldFindInformation;

int BYTES_PER_FLOAT = 4;
FloatBuffer vertexData;

float[] a_Result = new float[16];

public RendererClass(Context context){

    float[] myVertices = {

            // Front face
             0.0f,  0.0f,  -1.0f, 
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  -1.0f, 
             0.5f, -0.5f,  -1.0f, 
             0.5f,  0.5f,  -1.0f, 
            -0.5f,  0.5f,  -1.0f, 
            -0.5f, -0.5f,  -1.0f,

            // Back face
             0.0f,  0.0f, -2.0f, 
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -2.0f, 
             0.5f, -0.5f, -2.0f, 
             0.5f,  0.5f, -2.0f, 
            -0.5f,  0.5f, -2.0f, 
            -0.5f, -0.5f, -2.0f
    };

    ByteBuffer intermediateBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(myVertices.length*BYTES_PER_FLOAT);
    intermediateBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    vertexData = intermediateBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexData.put(myVertices);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig config) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    String vertexShaderCode =   "attribute vec4 myVertexPositionInsideOpenGL;"
                              + "uniform mat4 a_Result;"

                              + "void main(){" 
                              +     "gl_Position = a_Result*myVertexPositionInsideOpenGL;"                             
                              + "}";


    String fragmentShaderCode = "precision mediump float;" 
                              + "uniform vec4 myColorsInsideOpenGL;" 

                              + "void main(){" 
                              +     "gl_FragColor = myColorsInsideOpenGL;"
                              + "}";

    int vertexShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShaderID = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShaderID, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShaderID, fragmentShaderCode);

    GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShaderID);

    shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShaderID);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShaderID);

    GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);    
    GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram); 

    variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "myVertexPositionInsideOpenGL");
    variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "myColorsInsideOpenGL");
    variableToSayWhereTheMatrixShouldFindInformation = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "a_Result");

    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation);

    vertexData.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(variableToSayWhereTheVertexShaderShouldFindInformation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexData);

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {

    Matrix.orthoM(a_Result, 0, -4, 4, -4, 4, 4, -4);
    Matrix.rotateM(a_Result, 0, MainActivity.variable2, 1, 0, 0);

}

GL10 a;

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {

    onSurfaceChanged(a, 1, 1);

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);     

    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(variableToSayWhereTheMatrixShouldFindInformation, 1, false, a_Result, 0);

    glUniform4f(variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 6);

    glUniform4f(variableToSayWhereTheFragmentShaderShouldFindInformation, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 6, 6);


}

}
```